# Overflow from serial port in Wine/Virtualbox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, wine, serial-port

I'm trying to read the data saved on a minimax B4 sensor connected to my Ubuntu 20.04 machine using a serial port via USB (mounted as `/dev/ttyACM0`). The program reading the data is an old Windows one running either on Wine or Virtualbox (the problem is the same in both cases).

I can connect the sensor and get some data but it looks like there are problems with the data flow: either it goes in a sort of loop or I get an unspecified error when trying to download the data. I tried to change the speed using `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 1152000` (or lower down to 9600) but that does not seem to make much difference.

I'm not a programmer and don't know what to do more. Any help is highly appreciated.